# MomentJS and timezone/UTC calculations

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a JavaScript date object which has come from an API; but when I use Moment to do some date manipulation, the timezone component is messed up and the resulting date now uses GMT local time:

```
var d = new Date("2018-09-30T00:00:00+10:00");
var m1 = moment(d).toDate(); // 2018-09-29T14:00:000Z
var m2 = moment.utc(d).toDate(); // 2018-09-29T14:00:000Z
```

How do I preserve my timezone information so that when I start adding days/hours etc, the resulting value remains in the +10:00 timezone?

If I look at the `moment` object created in e.g. Firefox debugger, I can see that `m1` has `_tzm:600` and `_isUTC:false`, whereas `m2` has `_tzm:600` and `_isUTC:true` but in both cases, the wrapped `_d` is `2018-09-29T14:00:000Z` and not `2018-09-30T00:00:00+10:00` as I would hope.

If I call:

```
var m3 = moment(d).format(); // 2018-09-03T00:00:00+10:00
```

then everything is okay, but now I have a `string` rather than a `Date` object

Answer (score 0):

By [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), Date objects are just in UTC:

> Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in
>   time. Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of
>   milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

The browser usually will transform this to local time, though.

I am unsure what you are trying to accomplish. However, in general, for printing back the date in a different timezone, string would be the way. As for timezone manipulation, [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) might be your place to go.

That being said, if your use case is simple, you can try directly parsing the string date moment and using `parseZone`. It will allow you to capture the exact date and get timezone information as well.

Just a small snippet showing this.

```js
const date = '2018-09-30T00:00:00+10:00';

const parseZone = moment.parseZone(date);
console.log('Original time: ', parseZone.format());

const offsetTimezone = parseZone.format('Z');
console.log('Timezone', offsetTimezone);

const utcOffset = parseZone.utcOffset();
console.log('Offset from UTC in minutes', utcOffset);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```