# Get the current time in momentJS date

Tags: javascript, date, time, format, momentjs

I need help to format the date to get the result in the desired format.

```
Expected: Sun Sep 30 2018 20:39:52 GMT+0530
```

```
Recieved: Sun Sep 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530
```

### What I'm trying:

```
console.log(moment('2018-09-30'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample code does not contain a date with time.

However, to print in a certain desired format, you can use `moment.format()`. See the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

```js
const m = moment('2018-09-30');
console.log(m.format());
console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm:ss ZZ'));
console.log(m.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss \\G\\M\\T ZZ'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you are actually sending the time in your samples, the code would still be the same. Unless you want to keep the original timezone. For that, I have answered the same question some minutes ago. Here is the [reply for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52578801/7684576).

Comment: Could you pinpoint the difference? That'd help us help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
moment.parseZone('2016-05-03T22:15:01+02:00').local().format();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(moment('2018-09-30')); won't give you `Sun Sep 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530` this.
```

it will print out and an moment object.

if you need the exact format you may not need moment.js,

```
console.log(new Date().toString()) //"Sun Nov 04 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want current time and output in your desired format, you should do like this:

```
moment().format('dddd MMM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS Z')
```

output: **Monday Oct 01 2018 03:10:39 +10:00**

you don't need to pass the current date to moment()

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
const currentTime = moment().format('HH:mm:ss'); // 20:39:52
const dateWithCurrentTime = moment(`2018-09-30 ${currentTime}`); // 2018-09-30 20:39:52
```